# Rotate a mesh to align its surface to that of another mesh

Tags: math, geometry

I have two meshes which I want to align. I need to put the (bottom surface of the) cylinder on top of the box as shown. I got the normal vectors of both surfaces (v1,v2).

[image]

[image]

How do I calculate the needed rotation for the cylinders surface to face the exact opposite direction of the top of the box?

[image]

I'm grateful for any advice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Matrix method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d). [Quaternion method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another) (easier).

Comment: see [Problem superimposing and aligning 3D triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52163563/2521214)