# Space complexity of matrix inversion, determinant and adjoint

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity, matrix-inverse

I want to check the space complexity of

- matrix inversion,
- matrix adjoint and
- matrix determinant.

Most of the literature mention the time complexity (for the inversion there are $O(n^3)$ solutions and for the determinant $O(n^4)$ and $O(n^3)$). But I haven't been able to find literature where mentions the space complexity for these three operations.

Do you guys know any good references covering the **space complexity** of some algorithms for these operations ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination (assuming there are no precision issues) to find both an inversion and a determinant, and it requires O(n^3) time and O(n^2) space. Since the output for inversion requires O(n^2) space, it's space-optimal for this operation.

Comment: some special matrices (like orthonormal rotational and homogenuous transform matrices) can be inverted in-place so `O(1)` space using transposing of rotation part of matrix and correcting the rest by simple `matrix*vector` multiplication. However standard approach complexity heavily depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Spektre neither transpose nor matrix multiplication are O(1)

Comment: @dmuir transpose is `O(1)` space its done inplace so the result is already allocated. but youre right `matrix*vector` is `O(m)` space where `m` is dimensionality of the space the matrix represent usually `m=n-1` where `n` is size of square matrix. here example [`matrix_inv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293434/2521214) for 4x4 3D matrix